# C# WCF System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'ManagedService'

Tags: c#, exception, configuration

In a WCF application I have some custom configuration classes for use in `app.config`. However, I'm getting the following Stack Trace from the WCF Service Host (It attempts to retrieve the custom configuration in the constructor of the WCF service):

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   element 'ManagedService'. (Service.dll.config line 8)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[]
>   keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult,
>   Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at ManagementService..ctor() in
>   ManagementService.cs:line 42    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, RuntimeType
>   declaringType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.CreateImplementation(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2&
>   implementedContracts)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.CreateServiceHost(Type type,
>   ServiceKind kind)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo
>   info) System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   element 'ManagedService'. (Service.dll.config line 8)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[]
>   keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult,
>   Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
>   configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean
>   getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
>   resultRuntimeObject)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
>   configKey)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName)    at ManagementService..ctor() in
>   ManagementService.cs:line 42

(Sorry for the nasty stack trace).

I've looked at tons of tutorials and other questions here about this error and none of the suggestions or solutions have gone anywhere.

Here's the relevant portion of the `app.config`

```
<configSections>
     <section name="ManagedServices" type="Service.Configuration.ManagedServicesSection, Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral " allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" restartOnExternalChanges="false" />
</configSections>
  <ManagedServices>
     <services>
        <ManagedService serviceAssembly="Service" serviceType="Service.Runnables.HostManagerRunner" identifier="HostManager" priority="0">
           <clear />
        </ManagedService>
        <ManagedService serviceAssembly="Service" serviceType="Service.Runnables.TimeoutMonitor" identifier="TimeoutMonitor" priority="0">
           <add key="timeoutLength" value="30" />
           <add key="runInterval" value="30" />
        </ManagedService>
     </services>
  </ManagedServices>
```

Basically, this WCF service is used to manage other services which are loaded and started dynamically (informed via this configuration) on start up.

`<ManagedServices>` is from the `ManagedServicesSection` which inherits from `ConfigurationSection`

```
public class ManagedServicesSection : ConfigurationSection
{

  [ConfigurationProperty("services", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
  public ManagedServiceCollection ServiceCollection
  {
     get { return (ManagedServiceCollection) base["services"]; }
  }

}
```

As you can see from this, `<services>` is a `MangedServiceCollection` which inherits from `ConfigurationElementCollection`

```
public class ManagedServiceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{

  public ManagedServiceCollection()
  {
  }

  public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
  {
     get
     {
        return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap;
     }
  }

  public ManagedService this[int index]
  {
     get { return BaseGet(index) as ManagedService; }
     set
     {
        if (BaseGet(index) != null)
           BaseRemoveAt(index);

        BaseAdd(index, value);
     }
  }

  public ManagedService this[string name]
  {
     get { return BaseGet(name) as ManagedService; }
     set 
     { 
        if (BaseGet(name) != null)
           BaseRemove(name);

        BaseAdd(value);
     }
  }

  protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
  {
     return new ManagedService();
  }

  protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
  {
     return ((ManagedService)element).Identifier;
  }
}
```

This collection holds `ManagedService`s which inherit from `ConfigurationElement`:

```
public class ManagedService : ConfigurationElement
{
  [ConfigurationProperty("serviceAssembly", IsRequired = true)]
  public string ServiceAssembly
  {
     get { return (string) this["serviceAssembly"]; }
     set { this["serviceAssembly"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("serviceType", DefaultValue = "IRunnable", IsRequired = true)]
  public string ServiceType 
  { 
     get { return (string) this["serviceType"]; }
     set { this["serviceType"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("identifier", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
  public string Identifier
  {
     get { return (string) this["identifier"]; }
     set { this["identifier"] = value; }
  }


  [ConfigurationProperty("priority", DefaultValue = 0, IsRequired = false)]
  public int Priority
  {
     get { return (int) this["priority"]; }
     set { this["priority"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("serviceParameters", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
  public ServiceParameterCollection ServiceParameters
  {
     get { return (ServiceParameterCollection)base["serviceParamters"]; }
  }
}
```

The code may be easier to look at in this pastie [pastie.org/private/jkiylqsrklpcdbtfdrajq](http://pastie.org/private/jkiylqsrklpcdbtfdrajq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not complied your sample, ServiceParameterCollection was missing... so I have prepared you my working samle. Here we go...

First lets create config classes, take notice on AddItemName ConfigurationCollection parameter (I think this is what you are missing in your code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GP.Solutions.WF.DocumentProvider.Entities.SharePoint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base SharePoint 2010 provider contiguration
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class SharePoint2010Settings : ConfigurationSection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// DocumentStorageRoot
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("SiteUrl", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
        public string SiteUrl
        {
            get { return (string)base["SiteUrl"]; }
            set { base["SiteUrl"] = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// TitleProperty
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("TitleProperty", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "Title")]
        public string TitleProperty
        {
            get { return (string)base["TitleProperty"]; }
            set { base["TitleProperty"] = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ProvideFileAsLink
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("ProvideFileAsLink", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = true)]
        public bool ProvideFileAsLink
        {
            get { return (bool)base["ProvideFileAsLink"]; }
            set { base["ProvideFileAsLink"] = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// DocumentCategories
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("DocumentCategories")]
        public SharePointDocumentCategoryCollection DocumentCategories
        {
            get { return (SharePointDocumentCategoryCollection)base["DocumentCategories"]; }
            set { base["DocumentCategories"] = value; }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration element that holds SharePointDocumentCategory collection
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SharePointDocumentCategory), AddItemName = "DocumentCategory", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
    public class SharePointDocumentCategoryCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new SharePointDocumentCategory();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((SharePointDocumentCategory)element).CategoryName;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration element that holds information for specific document category
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class SharePointDocumentCategory: ConfigurationElement
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// CategoryName
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("CategoryName", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
        public string CategoryName
        {
            get { return (string)base["CategoryName"]; }
            set { base["CategoryName"] = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// FolderName
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("FolderName", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
        public string FolderName
        {
            get { return (string)base["FolderName"]; }
            set { base["FolderName"] = value; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// TitleProperty
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("OverwriteFiles", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = true)]
        public bool OverwriteFiles
        {
            get { return (bool)base["OverwriteFiles"]; }
            set { base["OverwriteFiles"] = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// DocumentCategories
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("CategoryFields")]
        public SharePointCategoryFieldsCollection CategoryFields
        {
            get { return (SharePointCategoryFieldsCollection)base["CategoryFields"]; }
            set { base["CategoryFields"] = value; }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configuration element that holds SharePointDocumentCategory collection
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SharePointDocumentCategory), AddItemName = "CategoryField", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
    public class SharePointCategoryFieldsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new SharePointCategoryField();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((SharePointCategoryField)element).FieldName;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that determines specific field
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class SharePointCategoryField : ConfigurationElement
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// FolderName
        /// </summary>
        [ConfigurationProperty("FieldName", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
        public string FieldName
        {
            get { return (string)base["FieldName"]; }
            set { base["FieldName"] = value; }
        }
    }

}
```

And here is web.config part:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="CustomConfiguration">
      <section name="SharePoint2010Section" type="GP.Solutions.WF.DocumentProvider.Entities.SharePoint.SharePoint2010Settings,CustomConfiguration" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true"/>
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

  <CustomConfiguration>

    <SharePoint2010Section SiteUrl="http://server" TitleProperty="Title" ProvideFileAsLink="false">
        <DocumentCategories>

          <DocumentCategory CategoryName="Vhodni računi" FolderName="" OverwriteFiles="true">
            <CategoryFields>
              <CategoryField FieldName="Datum" />
              <CategoryField FieldName="Vrednost" />
            </CategoryFields>
          </DocumentCategory>

          <DocumentCategory CategoryName="Zahtevek za dopust" FolderName="" OverwriteFiles="true">
            <CategoryFields>
              <CategoryField FieldName="Datum od" />
              <CategoryField FieldName="Datum do" />
            </CategoryFields>
          </DocumentCategory>

        </DocumentCategories>
    </SharePoint2010Section>
  </CustomConfiguration>
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I saw this in the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx and tried it. The MSDN page says that nesting a section element in a section group is **optional**

Comment: Also, when I tried it I got a different error. It then says `No ManagedServices section in configuration`

Comment: Ok, then we are getting forward

Comment: I think I can see the problem here... you are using collection, but missing addtional attributes

Comment: I will post you my sample so you can compare it

Comment: Sample is posted. Take notice on attributes I have placed on classes. This will do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. I had several other changes to do after the attributes, but I got it all working.