# Can I move values from settings.settings file to web.config file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, asmx

When I added a web reference to a ASMX web service to my web project, it created a proxy, but with some settings in settings.setting file.  Is there a way to move them to web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

If required you can remove default settings and create some custom settings (appSettings can be used also). Here is one of my posts how to create custom settings inside web.config:

[C# WCF System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'ManagedService'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824301/c-sharp-wcf-system-configuration-configurationerrorsexception-unrecognized-elem/12824424#12824424)

But you will have to set service client properties using code (read custom settings, set client properties).

Hope this answers your question.