# Unable to create a custom section for web.config

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, app-config, configuration-files

I created a custom section in the web.config file but it isn't able to load my custom type that is going to manage the section.

Here are the definitions:

```
<configSections>
<section
        name="MembershipProviders"
        type="MyApp.BusinessObjects.MembershipProviderFactory.MembershipProvidersSection"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
</configSections>


namespace MyApp.BusinessObjects
{
    public class MembershipProviderFactory
    {
        internal virtual IMembershipProvider Create()
        {
        }

        public class MembershipProvidersSection : ConfigurationSection
        {
            public class AddElement: ConfigurationElement
            {
                [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey  = true, IsRequired = true)]
                public string Name
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return this["name"].ToString();
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        this["name"] = value;
                    }
                }

                [ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true)]
                public string FullyQualifiedTypeName
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return this["type"].ToString();
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        this["type"] = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public class AddElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
            {
                protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
                {
                    return new AddElement();
                }

                protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
                {
                    return ((AddElement)element).Name;
                }
            }


            [ConfigurationProperty("currentProvider", IsRequired = false)]
            public string CurrentProvider
            {
                get
                {
                    return this["currentProvider"].ToString();
                }
                set
                {
                    this["currentProvider"] = value;
                }
            }

            [ConfigurationProperty("add", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
            public AddElementCollection Instances
            {
                get { return (AddElementCollection)this["add"]; }
                set { this["add"] = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a run-time exception that says:

*An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for MembershipProviders: Could not load type 'MyApp.BusinessObjects.MembershipProviderFactory.MembershipProvidersSection'.*

**Update**

I also included the actual section in the config file as follows:

```
<MembershipProviders currentProvider ="DefaultMembershipProvider" />
```

I still get the same exception.

Comment: What does your membership providers section actually look like in Web.config?

Comment: I haven't included one yet. Can a section be optional? That is, can I have the declaration of the section but not the actual section itself present in the web.config?

Comment: The section can be optional. You can add a ConfigurationProperty attribute to a configuration section or element with IsRequired set to false: `[ConfigurationProperty("elementName", IsRequired = false)]`

Comment: Thank you. As per that, then, I didn't do anything wrong. However, I have still included the section now. I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the assembly name as part of the `type` attribute:

```
<section
    name="MembershipProviders"
    type="Namespace.TheCustomSection, TheAssemblyNameGoesHere"
    allowLocation="true"
    allowDefinition="Everywhere"
/>
```

**EDIT**
I didn't notice that the `MembershipProvidersSection` class is a *nested* class.
The type name should be:

```
MyApp.BusinessObjects.MembershipProviderFactory+MembershipProvidersSection
```

Comment: Not if it is the current assembly?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: There is no "current assembly" when the config file is parsed.

Comment: Exactly. So, it is not a requirement to pass the assembly name in the config when the type you want to load is inside the same assembly.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: No, the assembly name **is** required. There is no concept of a "current assembly". You must **always** specify the assembly name.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, Richard is right. It will not work without assembly name.

Comment: This article implies that the assembly name is required only if the config section handler code is outside the currently executing assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Underneath the section entitled 'To add a custom section handler to an ASP.NET configuration file', point 2: Ensure that the type attribute of the section element matches the manifest of the assembly (ensure that you specify both the correct namespace and type name).

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: See my edit; the type name for a nested class uses a `+` instead of a `.` between the parent class name and the nested class name.

Comment: Thank you, Richard. With the + it worked now. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing assembly name where you are declaring type:

```
MyApp.BusinessObjects.MembershipProviderFactory.MembershipProvidersSection,?
```

Take a look at one of my posts about custom configuration:
[C# WCF System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'ManagedService'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824301/c-sharp-wcf-system-configuration-configurationerrorsexception-unrecognized-elem/12824424#12824424)